# Two errors: 'No member named' and 'Excess elements in struct initializer' when trying to 'make' PyQt4?

Tags: python, c++, makefile, pyqt4, fatal-error

I am having problems using the make function after I've used configure-ng.py with PyQt4. It gives me the error message

```
anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4_gpl_mac-4.12/QtCore/sipQtCorecmodule.cpp:5037:5: error: 
  no member named 'api_call_procedure_method' in '_sipAPIDef'
sipCallProcedureMethod(sipGILState, sipErrorHandler, sipPySelf, sipMethod, "D", ...
```

and

```
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4_gpl_mac-4.12/QtCore/sipQtCorecmodule.cpp:8896:91: error: 
  excess elements in struct initializer
  ...0, SIP_TYPE_ENUM, sipNameNr_QXmlStreamReader__ReadElementTextBehaviour, {0}, 0}, sip...
```

Eventually, there are so many errors that I get the following:

```
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [sipQtCorecmodule.o] Error 1
make: *** [sub-QtCore-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

I've already made sure that my PYTHONPATH reaches this location first (and I've made sure SIP was here as well). 
I'm just not sure where to go from here.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like your build environment is out of date. Paste your library and OS versions.

Comment: library: Accounts  Fonts   Printers
Address Book Plug-Ins GameKit   PubSub
Application Scripts Google   Receipts
Application Support Group Containers Safari
Assistant  IdentityServices Saved Application State
Assistants  Input Methods  Screen Savers
Audio   Internet Plug-Ins Scripts
Autosave Information Keyboard  Services
Caches   Keyboard Layouts Sharing
Calendars  KeyboardServices Sounds
CallServices  Keychains  Speech
ColorPickers  LanguageModeling Spelling
Colors   LaunchAgents  Spotlight
Compositions  Logs   Suggestions
Containers  Mail   SyncedPreferences

Comment: Cookies   Maps   TextWrangler
CoreData  Messages  Voices
CoreFollowUp  Metadata  WebKit
Dictionaries  PDF Services  Workflows
Dropbox   Passes   com.apple.nsurlsessiond
Favorites  PreferencePanes  iMovie
FontCollections  Preferences  iTunes

Comment: OS version 10.12.1

Comment: I updated my OS to version 10.12.3 and I have the same problem.